# Twilio and Browser to Browser Calls - Token Issue

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I am working through this code:
https://github.com/rajkumarbhatia/twilio-audio-call-laravel

The corresponding tutorial video is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-NQvfslrmA

I have everything relatively squared away in that I am able to pull up the page on my domain. However, on the right side of the page in the status updates section I get:

```
> Requesting Capability Token...
> Could not get a token from server!
```

In Developer Tools I see a 404 error for:
filename /twilio-audio-call-laravel/token

I am not clear if this means the directory must be named /twilio-audio-call-laravel/ ... It does not appear so, because I changed the directory to that name and received the same error.

I am a bit of a newbie in terms of working with Laravel and Twilio and any help is appreciated. I checked the routes directory and just see this for web.php:

```
Route::get('/index',[Controller::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/',[Controller::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/voice',[Controller::class, 'voice']);
Route::post('/token',[Controller::class, 'token']);
```

I have this running in a sub-directory of a WordPress site because eventually I want to have click to call buttons browser to browser via Twilio with a call button on a WordPress page and then have a separate page where an agent answers the call from a website visitor. Not sure if it is a directory issue or where to start with that 404 error.

All the code examples from Twilio use Laravel with PHP so just trying to navigate it step-by-step.

Thanks again!

Comment: Your `token` route is failing to obtain a token. You need to figure out why it is failing to get a token. Possibly because your API key is invalid.

Comment: What is the URL in the browser that you see when you run the application and open the home page?

Comment: _"I have this running in a sub-directory of a WordPress site"_ - that's likely part of the problem; unless you added an explicit exception for this path in WP's own URL rewriting, this will get routed into WordPress - and that doesn't find any content to serve in its database under the "slug" `/twilio-audio-call-laravel/token`